# How to reconfigure two hard disk already cloned in RAID1 without rewriting all?

Tags: btrfs, raid1

I have cloned my existing hard disk first, so that I have now two exact copies. Now I would like to setup a RAID1 with them, but avoiding to rewrite the disk added, because I don't have some other storage for backups and I don't want to risk to have only a single copy.

Normal procedure to add `/dev/sdb` to `/dev/sda` from no RAID configuration at all and from`/dev/sda` would be if I am not mistaken:

```
btrfs device add /dev/sdb /
btrfs balance start -dconvert=raid1 -mconvert=raid1
```

But the btrfs-device manual says:

> If applicable, a whole device discard (TRIM) operation is performed
>   prior to adding the device. A device with existing filesystem detected
>   by blkid(8) will prevent device addition and has to be forced. The
>   operation is instant and does not affect existing data.

How should I perform it?

Comment: Before setting up RAID1, please do something about not having backups. That should take priority over the RAID1 setup.

Answer (score 0):

Byte for byte clone of a btrfs is very dangerous, read this:

https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Gotchas#Block-level_copies_of_devices

The only way to convert your existing btrfs to btrfs RAID1 is to execute the commands you mentioned in your question but before that you'll have to manually wipe one of the drives (`wipefs -a /dev/sdX`) since the btrfs you want to expand has to be mounted and you should never attempt to mount it while a block device with a copy of that btrfs is visible to the Kernel.
If you have accidentally done that at some point, it is possible that you corrupted either copy or both, so at least run a scrub and a read-only check on the btrfs you want to expand (disconnect the other drive from the system for this of course).

If you have >50% free space in your btrfs' you might be able to juggle them around in a way that always keeps at least 2 copies on 2 devices while converting but with full drive btrfs' that's even harder compared to partitions.